# Error when adding a new build stage on Bluemix DevOps Services

Tags: git, github, ibm-cloud, devops

I imported a git repository from github into Bluemix DevOps Services. Deployment works fine after creating the repository, `manifest.yml`, setting up the code base from "Edit Code" and launching it successfully.

However, when I tried to add a new build stage from "Build & Deploy", I received the following error message at the top of the page:

> There was a problem loading the Git branches

My settings are as follows:

> Input Type: SCM Repository
>
> Git URL: https://github.com/juslee/agar.io-clone.git
>
> Branch: Error
>
> Stage Trigger: Automatically execute jobs when a change is pushed to Git

The error image: http://i61.tinypic.com/14jnln7.jpg

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Can you update your post with screenshots of the stages and the config info for the stages?

Comment: @JeffSloyer can't post screenshots yet because my reputation points ain't high enough.

Comment: Can you post them to another image sharing service then post links to the images here?

Comment: Added the error image: http://i61.tinypic.com/14jnln7.jpg

Comment: Does the branch Error exist?  Why arent you using the master branch?

Comment: There is no "Error" branch.

Comment: your branch is set to "Error" in your screen shot.  It should be master.

Comment: It is because there's an "Error" retrieving the branches.

Comment: Can you try importing the project again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently a limitation using "Build & Deploy" with GitHub repositories that have a dot in their name.

To work around that you can:

1. Delete the Bluemix DevOps Services project
2. Rename the repository from "agar.io-clone" to, for example, "agar-io-clone"
3. Create a new project and link it to the repository

**Update: The limitation has been removed**

We are working on removing this limitation

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Deploy to Bluemix button below.  It references https://bluemix.net/deploy?repository=https://github.com/juslee/agar-io-clone.git.

[image]

I just deployed the application and it worked fine.

Here are some screenshots of my stages.

Make sure you have the branch set to `master` in the build build stage input, screenshot below.

[image: stages]
[image: build stage input]
[image: build stage]
[image: deploy stage]

Comment: Could you try your process with this git repo instead and you'll see the problem @jeffsloyer - https://github.com/huytd/agar.io-clone